# Mapbox GL JS flyTo triggered by scroll position not always working

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to use Mapbox GL JS to create a map that updates (including location, style and filters) as text moves on and off screen.

As in [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/scroll-fly-to/) I have created an array containing the locations to fly to, where 'first' and 'second' are the ids of the sections of my text.

```
var locations = {
'first': {
    center: [145.7, -17.8],
    zoom: 4.2,
    speed: 0.5
},
'second': {
    center: [148, -17.8],
    zoom: 5,
    speed: 0.5
},
'third': {
    center: [148, -18],
    zoom: 5.5,
    speed: 0.5
}}
```

I am using the library Waypoints.js to trigger the scroll events:

```
const $textSection = $('.text-section');

$(document).ready(function() {

    $textSection.each(function(){

        let _this = this;
        let sectionName = $(this).attr('id');

        var inViewBottom = new Waypoint({
            element: _this,
            handler: function (direction) {
                if (direction == 'down'){
                    map.flyTo(locations[sectionName]);
                    console.log(locations[sectionName]);
                    updateMap(sectionName);
                }
            },
            offset: '85%'
        });

});
```

In addition to [#flyTo](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#flyto) the waypoint also calls the function updateMap, which triggers other changes to the map:

```
function updateMap (sectionName) {

    if (sectionName == "first") {
        popup.addTo(map);
    } else {
        popup.remove();
    };

    if (sectionName == "first") {
        map.setPaintProperty('layer-1', 'line-opacity', 0.4);
    } else {
        map.setPaintProperty('layer-1', 'line-opacity', 0);
    };

    if (sectionName == "first") {
        map.setLayoutProperty('layer-2', 'visibility', 'none');
        $("#map-key").css("visibility", "hidden"); 
    } else {
        map.setLayoutProperty('layer-2', 'visibility', 'visible');
        $("#map-key").css("visibility", "visible"); 
    };

    if (sectionName == "second") {
        filterYear = ['==', ['number', ['get', 'Year']], 1998];
        map.setFilter("layer-2", filterYear);
    } else if (sectionName == "third") {
        filterYear = ['==', ['number', ['get', 'Year']], 2002];
        map.setFilter("layer-2", filterYear);
    }

}
```

Around 60% of the time this code works perfectly. But the rest of the time while everything is updateMap() executes, the flyTo animation doesn't work. I can't work out why, since other the code in the Waypoint works, and the console.log() still generates the object with the location data.

Interestingly, if I put updateMap() ahead of flyTo, the flyTo animation doesn't work at all, so I'm wondering if one of the other Mapbox GL methods called in updateMap() is interfering with flyTo some of the time. I tried using a setTimeout to delay when updateMap() is called, but it didn't seem to help.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!